# How to use Eclipselink @Multitenant in JSF/EJB?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

The @Multitenant support in Eclipselink 2.3 looks really interesting, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use it in a JSF or EJB which injects an EntityManager with @PersistenceContext.  The EclipseLink docs are pretty clear that @PersistenceContext injection doesn't work in this case, but you could inject an EntityManagerFactory via @PersistenceUunit instead.

Still, what I'm not seeing is how to manage the lifecycle of an EntityManager you might create via injected EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() - in particular, when to close the resulting EntityManager, and how to participate in transactions.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Or am I missing something obvious?

See also: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant

**UPDATE**

I had some success with @PersistenceContext (EntityManager) injection and then passing parameters to EclipseLink via session listener.  I'm not 100% sure this is the right answer and would appreciate confirmation that it isn't creating a non-obvious race condition or thread-safety issue.

For example:

```
public static class TenantListener extends SessionEventAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postAcquireClientSession(SessionEvent event) {
        long tenantId = **business logic**;
        event.getSession().setProperty("eclipselink.tenant-id", tenantId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using events is fine.

You could also inject the EntityManager and set the property, or inject the EntityManagerFactory and use joinTransaction() to join the active JTA transaction.

Comment: Thanks.  Am I understanding correctly that a "client session" is scoped to a single transaction or operation, so I don't need to worry about tenant leakage to another thread?

I think the session event listener will work best.  There isn't always a single obvious place to set properties on an injected EntityManager, and the thought of using an EMF and having to have finally { em.close(); } everywhere is unappealing.